# Appium-python `**urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4723): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

### The problem

The problem i'm facing here is im getting the following error  [`**urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4723): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd691cf0af0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))**`]  while connecting appium python code to android emulater device
Briefly describe the issue you are experiencing (or the feature you want to see added to Appium). Tell us what you were trying to do and what happened instead. Remember, this is *not* a place to ask questions. For that, go to http://discuss.appium.io!

### Environment

- windows 11 OS
- Pycharm Professional IDE
- Emulator version Android 11
- Appium latest app from offical site

### Link to Appium Logs

> Connected to pydev debugger (build 223.8617.48)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/mohanraj/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mis-automation-L9yvBObc-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
> conn = connection.create_connection(
> File "/home/mohanraj/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mis-automation-L9yvBObc-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
> raise err
> File "/home/mohanraj/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mis-automation-L9yvBObc-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
> sock.connect(sa)
> ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/mohanraj/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mis-automation-L9yvBObc-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(
> File "/home/mohanraj/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mis-automation-L9yvBObc-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
> conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
> File "/home/mohanraj/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mis-automation-L9yvBObc-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
> super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
> File "/home/mohanraj/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1285, in request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
> File "/home/mohanraj/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1331, in _send_request
> self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
> File "/home/mohanraj/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
> File "/home/mohanraj/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1040, in _send_output
> self.send(msg)
> File "/home/mohanraj/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 980, in send
> self.connect()
> File "/home/mohanraj/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mis-automation-L9yvBObc-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
> conn = self._new_conn()
> File "/home/mohanraj/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mis-automation-L9yvBObc-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
> raise NewConnectionError(
> urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd691cf0af0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/mohanraj/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mis-automation-L9yvBObc-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(
> File "/home/mohanraj/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/mis-automation-L9yvBObc-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4723): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd691cf0af0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
> python-BaseException
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

### Code To reproduce issue

```
from time import sleep

from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy

desired_caps = {
    "deviceName": "Pixel 4a API 30",
    "platformName": "Android",
    "udid": "emulator-5554",
    "version": 11,
    "app": "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Downloads\\com.indigo.new.apk"
}

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```